# GWT upload samples not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, upload

because i want to have smarter upload in my site, i downloaded *gwtupload-samples-0.6.1* from http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

and i imported the war file to eclipse IDE.

then i added the GWT configuration to the project and now it's a GWT project.
but the project want run, and still i see errors like "**GWTCBox cannot be resolved to a type**" and "**GWTCPopupBox cannot be resolved to a variable**" .

i think i should import more libraries , but i don't know what should i import!
any body can help me pleas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As maneesh wrote, the key is gwtchismes. What you have is a problem with the libraries your project uses.

You have to visit GWT-Chismes dowload area and get this library's JAR file: http://gwtchismes.googlecode.com/files/gwtchismes-0.9.7.jar

After that, you have to copy this file to the lib directory of your project and update your classpath to include it.

After this, these warnings should go away.

No additional import needed. Btw, you are never forced to use any import. Imports are not intended to "pull" some libraries to your project (the classpath is intended for this); imports are only compilation-time features of a language like Java that ease your life by shortening class names inside the source code of your programs. But they are not required. You can do certain things if you use them, but you don't lose any privilege of using any object if you don't use them (you'll just have to write more).

Answer (score 0):

GWTCBox is from gwtchismes http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/